# Faster way of writing constructors?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have to use a lot of `Point` constructors, like so :

```
function setLoc(o:*, loc:Point):void
{
    o.x = loc.x;
    o.y = loc.y;
}

setLoc(obj1, new Point(25,50));
setLoc(obj2, new Point(13,-5));
setLoc(obj3, new Point(186.5,-23));
...
```

Is there a way to write these in a more compact way, maybe some macros or compiler tricks ? It is very tedious to have to write "new Point(...)" for such a simple Class. I wish I could do something like :

```
setLoc(obj1, (25,50));
```

(I dont want to change setLoc(o,p) to setLoc(o,px,py) but I guess thats the best solution)

Comment: Why not make an alternative `setLoc` which takes x and y as separate parameters? Seems the least-hacky to me. You can give it a different name to keep both options available, like `setXY`

Comment: as @Dave said, `setLock(obj1, 25, 50);` is shorter

Comment: I gave a bad example, the problem with setLoc(o,x,y) is readability with larger functions : `setTrajectory(o, xstart, ystart, xend, yend)` would look like `setTrajectory(obj1, 10, 0, 20, 30)` but it would be nicer to have it like so `setTrajectory(obj1, (10, 0), (20, 30))`, with some kind of implicit point declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
setLoc(obj1, {x:25, y:50});
```

Just change the type of the loc argument to Object:

```
function setLoc(o:*, loc:Object):void
{
    o.x = loc.x;
    o.y = loc.y;
}
```